# How do I format my labels using a log scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble formatting my y-axis labels the way I want.  I'd like them to be rounded to the nearest thousand.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(x=seq(1,10,by=1),y=sample(10000000,10))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', breaks=trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x), labels=comma)
```

[image]

How do I format my y labels so that they are rounded to the nearest thousand?  In other words, I'd like 7,943,000 displayed instead of 7,943,282.

Comment: You may try the `y2 = signif(y, 3)` to get the numbers rounded to the nearest thousand, and then suppress original y-label and put the `y2` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by changing the `labels` argument to `scale_y_continuous.` Here I used `round(x,-3)` to round the label value to the nearest 1000:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
df<-data.frame(x=seq(1,10,by=1),y=sample(10000000,10))
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()
p <- p +scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', 
                           breaks=trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x), 
                           labels = function(x)round(x,-3)
                           )
p
```

Which produces:
[image]